# Insert of XML file into Database in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-insert

I have create a table with 3 columns @UserDefinedSectionData with XML datatype, @UserDefinedModuleId with INT datatype and @UserDefinedTabId with INT datatype.

I need to insert the whole XML file into database, in T-SQL i need to read path from my local PC, example: C:\Websites\dnndev.me\XML\abc.xml, after read it and insert the whole xml into UserDefinedSectionData column which is XML datatype.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this syntax:

```
DECLARE @xml_data XML,
        @path_file nvarchar(260),
        @cmd nvarchar(max);

SET @path_file = N'C:\Folder\File.XML';

/* get XML file */
SET @cmd = 'SELECT @xmlText = BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '
            + '''' + @path_file + ''''
            + ', SINGLE_BLOB) x;';

EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, N'@xmlText XML OUTPUT', @xmlText = @xml_data OUTPUT;
```

You must grant permission to the account that runs SQL Server agent.

Comment: I'm glad to help. Please consider to accept the answer if it works.